Fire extinguishers for rural site with machinery
I’m loosely involved in a small scale, off-grid aggregate/mining site in Canada that has assorted machinery (diesel, gas, some hydraulics):

Trojan 3000 loader
Small International tractor converted to rough terrain forklift
Generators, compressors, and other small engine equipment
Pickup truck
Garage

After seeing a YouTube video of an excavator fire, I am planning to buy some fire extinguishers for the site's operator.
What kind of fire extinguishers are suitable? For example, three 4A60BC Rechargeable 10-lb extinguishers? One for the loader, one for the garage, and one for the truck.

You can interpret the 4A60BC rating as follows:

4A means that the extinguisher will put out a fire in wood, paper or trash equivalent to 4 x 1-1/4 gallons of water (which is 5 gallons).

60B means that it will put out a 60 square foot fire of burning liquid when properly used in a side to side sweeping motion.

C means that it is suitable for use on electrical fires without endangering the user.


So if you think the above rating is sufficient for a likely type of fire at the site, you're good. Additional extinguishers can be added in the future for greater firefighting capacity if needed, but three of this size is a good start.
When deciding on size of an extinguisher, remember that a small extinguisher right there where the fire starts is better than a much bigger and more capable extinguisher that you have to run and fetch.
